# How can I store a friend function in std::function

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers, friend

How do I store a friend function inside std::function?

```
#include <functional>

class SomeClass
{
    public:
    friend bool foo(int arg);
};

bool foobar(int);

class OtherClass
{
    public:
    void bar(){
        std::function<bool(int)> f; 
        f = foo; // undeclared identifier or foo was not declared in this scope
        std::function<bool(int)> g; 
        g = foobar; // is fine
    }
};
```

[Check this code snippet on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WozhY8zhM)

Comment: `friend bool foo(int arg);` this line means that there is a function in global namespace named `foo` which is a friend of `SomeClass`. It doesn't define/declare a function named `foo`.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175304/is-the-friend-declaration-a-real-declaration

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/ds66Tz89K

Comment: @codeling, nice article :-)